# Correct indentation (pretty print) of an SVG file with Apache Batik

Tags: java, svg, indentation, batik

I need to understand how apache batik indents the SVG file produced by the library.
I have the following code:

```
DOMImplementation domImpl = GenericDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();

        String svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        Document document = domImpl.createDocument(svgNS, "svg", null);

        SVGGeneratorContext ctx = SVGGeneratorContext.createDefault(document);

        SVGGraphics2D svgGenerator = new SVGGraphics2D(ctx, false);

        for(Drawable savedDrawable : cVwDrawLocal.getSavedDrawables()){
            if(savedDrawable instanceof GeoDrawable){
                savedDrawable.copyToGraphics(svgGenerator);
            }
        }

        boolean useCSS = true; // we want to use CSS style attributes

        String svgFile = svgFileName + ".svg";

        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(svgFile);
            Writer outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
            svgGenerator.stream(outputStreamWriter, useCSS);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And the produced SVG file is:

```
<g
  ><g style="fill:white; stroke-miterlimit:1; stroke-dasharray:1; stroke-dashoffset:1; stroke:white;"
    ><line y2="432" style="fill:none;" x1="873" x2="873" y1="432"
    /></g
    ><g style="fill:rgb(0,252,253); stroke-miterlimit:1; stroke-dasharray:0.1,5; stroke-width:2; stroke-dashoffset:1; stroke:rgb(0,252,253);"
    ><line y2="479" style="fill:none;" x1="901" x2="910" y1="490"
    /></g
    >
```

But I need something like this:

```
<g>
    <g style="fill:white; stroke-miterlimit:1; stroke-dasharray:1; stroke-dashoffset:1; stroke:white;">
        <line y2="432" style="fill:none;" x1="873" x2="873" y1="432"/>
    </g>
    <g style="fill:rgb(0,252,253); stroke-miterlimit:1; stroke-dasharray:0.1,5; stroke-width:2; stroke-dashoffset:1; stroke:rgb(0,252,253);">
        <line y2="479" style="fill:none;" x1="901" x2="910" y1="490"/>
    </g>
</g>
```

How can I obtain this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you care how it indents?

Comment: For a merge problem of different SVG files in one file. A "correct" indent would simplify this question.

Comment: Ok, I have found this solution that works for me:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I have found a solution that works for me:

```
public static boolean prettyPrintXml(File newFile) {

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);
            documentBuilderFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(newFile);

            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

            StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(newFile);
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
            transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: probably no longer relevant, but ran into the same issue and I've also found batik -svg-prettyprinter: http://people.apache.org/~clay/batik/svgpp.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Caution, pretty print can cause different outputs, e.g. if you have different tspan tags inside a text tag. The newline and indentation characters are causing a visual whitespace.

```
<text x="20" y="20"><tspan>abc</tspan><tspan>def</tspan></text>
```

is different to

```
<text x="20" y="20">
   <tspan>abc</tspan>
   <tspan>def</tspan>
</text>
```

First result: abcdef, second result: abc def